# Custom iOS framework for use with Swift project. Mach-O Type Dynamic and Static, both causing different issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift2

I'm using Xcode 7.1, iOS SDK 9.1.

I have created a Cocoa Touch Framework (MyFW) in Objective-C that uses a 3rd party framework (FW-A). I have added this FW-A to MyFW as a Linked Framework/Library since it's a dependency.

In my Sample App, I have added MyFW and a Podfile with FW-A as the dependency.

**Case 1:** MyFW has Mach-O Type = 'Dynamic Library':-

At runtime, there are warnings with classes of FW-A like "Class XYZ is implemented in both "MyFW" and "Sample App". One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. I checked many posts for this issue but couldn't find a viable solution.

**Case 2:** MyFW has Mach-O Type = 'Static Library' :-

The app does not throw any warnings or errors at compile-time or run-time. But when I create an IPA file of the Sample App and try to install on the device using iTunes; it fails to install every time.

***Question:***

Which issue in which case is easier to resolve?

As Umbrella frameworks are highly discouraged by Apple, I'm not taking that approach.

Comment: **Solution:** I understood what mistake I was making. The very concept of using Dynamic Frameworks is not requiring additional dependencies to be added. In my Sample App, I removed the Pod project with FW-A and built it with just the MyFW added and all the warnings disappeared. The IPA is also installing successfully.!